# How can I authorize my web api controller in my web site with Bearer token?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, bearer-token

I have an Asp.Net MVC core application with standard login functionality. I have added a web api controller to my project. I want to authorize the web api controller with bearer token. But only this controller. The rest of my website must work the way it is now. If I have it set in my startup.cs, I mean Bearer token functionality, that works but it destroy my website. I then get error 401. Is it possible to authorize only a controller with bearer token?

Comment: Yes, you just have to decorate your controller method with the [Authorize] attribute. It will limit the token validation to just that method.

Comment: I suggest that you could refer to [Selecting the scheme with the Authorize attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x#selecting-the-scheme-with-the-authorize-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rex's comment is accurate.  I'm including a code sample that will get you what you want (assuming JWT).

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
     services
          .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
          .AddJwtBearer(options =>
           {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
           {
            // omitted
           };
     });
```

**Your controller**

```
[Authorize(ADD OPTIONAL USER SCOPES/POLICIES)]
```

Add this attribute and pass-in optional scopes to limit access to specific users.